# Compare contents in text files line by line

Tags: c

My C exercise requires to compare 2 text files line by line
-meaning that
[image]

[image]

[image]

My plan is:

First, using fgets() function to read one line at the time of the string

Second, using sscanf() function to parse (ignore  the whitespace) the string and then compare them.

However, I got the problem that the code just read the first word of the string (line)
so I got incorrect result. But now when I changed my code, it always give me the "files different". Please help me. My logic is wrong ><
Here is my code

```
int comp_line(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2){
char l1[1024];
char l2[1024];
char w1[1024];
char w2[1024];
char *c1;
char *c2;

/*initialize*/
c1 = fgets(l1,1024,fp1);
c2 = fgets(l2,1024,fp2);

sscanf(w1,"%1023s",l1);
sscanf(w2,"%1023s",l2);

while (c1 != NULL && c2 != NULL && strcmp(w1,w2) == 0)
{   
    c1 = fgets(l1,1024,fp1);
    c2 = fgets(l2,1024,fp2);
    sscanf(w1,"%1023s",l1);
    sscanf(w1,"%1023s",l1);
    if(c1 != NULL && c2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("EOF 2");
        return 0;
    }
    if(c1 == NULL && c2 != NULL)
    {
        printf("EOF 1");
        return 0;
    }

}
if(strcmp(w1,w2) == 0)
{
    printf("\nfiles are equal");
    return 0;
}
else
{
    printf("\nfiles different");
    return 1;
}
return 0;
```

}

Thank you very much!

Comment: try printing out what you have stored in each of w1 and w2 after the sscanf, note that your code shows scanf(21,...) twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you've got your `sscanf()` arguments back to front; you need to scan from (some offset into) `l1` or `l2`, and assign to `w1` or `w2`, whereas at the moment you scan `w1` or `w2` and store the result into `l1` or `l2`.

To iterate over the line, you should probably use the little known `%n` format, which reports the offset in the buffer (input) where it appears.

```
char *c1;
char *c2;

while ((c1 = fgets(l1, 1024, fp1)),
       (c2 = fgets(l2, 1024, fp2)),
       c1 != NULL && c2 != NULL)
{
    int n1;
    int n2;

    char *line1 = l1;
    char *line2 = l2;

    int r1;
    int r2;
    while ((r1 = sscanf(line1, "%1023s%n", w1, &n1)),
           (r2 = sscanf(line2, "%1023s%n", w2, &n2)),
           r1 == 1 && r2 == 1)
    {
        if (strcmp(w1, w2) != 0)
            ...lines differ...
        line1 += n1;
        line2 += n2;
    }
    ...deal with r1 or r2 is zero while the other isn't...
}
...deal with c1 or c2 is null while the other isn't...
```

I've never had cause to use the comma operator quite like the two loop conditions use it, but it seems appropriate for this context.  I want both the `fgets()` operations to be executed even when the first one fails; likewise, I want both `sscanf()` operations to be executed even when the first one fails.  This code achieves that without repetition of the function calls.

The key point to reading multiple words from a single line is the `line1 += n1;` construct, adding the offset where the string conversion finished to the start position for the next scan.